# How can I insert a data from my table to a combobox read-only?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is a school activity, [here is the complete code.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KB0v-8vsqXgOe70eINdKp5VgoWoMOr6U/view?usp=sharing)

I want to insert data from my table value to Combobox read-only. I also can't clear the text from the two Combobox when they are in a read-only state. I also wish to remove auto highlighting for aesthetic purposes.

```
#Gender label and input box
data_label5 = Label(section3, text="Gender:")
data_label5.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=(30, 0), pady=3)
data_label5_entry = ttk.Combobox(section3, textvariable=t5, width=18, state="readonly")
data_label5_entry['values'] = ['Male', 'Female']
data_label5_entry.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=3)

# Employment Date label and inputbox
data_label10 = Label(section3, text="Employment Date:")
data_label10.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=(30, 0), pady=3)
data_label10_entry = DateEntry(section3, textvariable=t10, width=18, state="readonly")
data_label10_entry.set_date(None)
data_label10_entry.delete(0, 'end')
data_label10_entry.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=5, pady=3)
```

Comment: You're asking how to insert data to a read only system. Huh.

Comment: yes, is it possible?

Comment: You can insert data into a read-only combobox but you cannot type in it or edit the values

Comment: Can you send how does the data look like? At-least the format with dummy values.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how to do that, should I upload a database table export instead? in any case [here it is](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14O6UnaNnQgZN1d9UBQJ1P_QqO3YV6EMa/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What I meant to say it that when you read from a table, and fetch all the values, it returns a tuple. Can you show us that tuple.

Comment: Sorry I really have no idea. Can I provide a [screenshot](https://ibb.co/M9j0Km5) of the program instead? The value from gender column can't get fetch when I double click the row when the combobox state is readonly but when I remove the readonly state it works like other entry boxes.

Comment: Did you try `t5.set(...)`?

Comment: I haven't yet, can you give me example?

Comment: You can call `t5.set(...)` inside the callback triggered by double-click the row in the treeview (said in your comment).

Comment: Ohh I see another way to do it, thanks for the idea.

Comment: My only problem now is the unwanted highlighting whenever I choose from the combobox value.